# if statements inside loop to find min value c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

In my final for loop, I want to repeat the equations and adjust the value of Ea until I find the smallest value of 'difference of squares2' and its corresponding value of Ea. I'm not sure how the if statement would work so it will stop at the point rather than continuing in which case I wont find the minimum

```
int main()
{
int T[] = { 700,730,760,790,810,840,910,1000 };
double k[] = { 0.011,0.035,0.105,0.343,0.789,2.17,20,145 };
float Yhat[8] = {};
int n = 0;
float Ea = 150000; //kJ
float A = (1.1)*10E12;
float R = 8.3144598; //kj K mol-1
float bestchisquared = 0;
float BestEa = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
cout << "Temp (K): " <<  T[i] << endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    cout << "Rate (L mol-1 s-1): " <<  k[i] << endl;

}
float differenceofsquares = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    differenceofsquares += (k[i] - (A*exp(-Ea / (R*T[i]))))*(k[i] - (A*exp(-Ea / (R*T[i]))));
}


cout << "chi squared for 150kJ: " << differenceofsquares << endl;
float differenceofsquares2 = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    differenceofsquares2 += (k[i] - (A*exp(-Ea / (R*T[i]))))*(k[i] - (A*exp(-Ea / (R*T[i]))));


    if (differenceofsquares2 < differenceofsquares)
        Ea = Ea + 10000;
}
else if  bestchisquared = differenceofsquares;
}

cout <<"Pre-exponential coefficient = "<< A << endl;
cout << "Best chi squared = " << bestchisquared << endl;
cout << "Best Activation Energy = " << BestEa << endl;
system("Pause");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You are using  differenceofsquares2 +=  as the first line in the for loop. So the differenceofsquares2 will never reduce itself as you are compounding  (+=) the variable. For finding the minimum, you will have to loop through the whole for loop and note the lowest differenceofsquares

Comment: but can i not find the min using an if statement?

Comment: you can but you will need another variable. read the result of the equation in a temp variable. If that variable is less than differenceofsquares2 , then copy the temp value to differenceofsquares2

Comment: thanks, could you explain where i put this in the code?

Comment: inside the for loop, declare float tempResult = [expression]; if (tempResult < differenceofsquares2) differenceofsquares2  = tempResult; Also the else if outside for looks weird.

Comment: ok thanks. I have done this but it is just returning 0. Where should I have the condition to add 10000 to Ea for each future loop?

Comment: Put out print statements to understand what's happening in the code. I have to go but will check in a few hours...